# I have installed Anaconda and I have installed pygame as well, but still got an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, agent

So, I have installed Anaconda3 64 bit and TensorFlow, matplotlib, and I have also installed pygame, but I still got an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`

In Anaconda, I have made a new environment and that has all of the packages I have installed and I open jupyter notebook from this environment. Still the error is there.

In Anaconda command prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\Eszter>pip install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\eszter\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)
```

Part of the code is this:
**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
from agent import Agent
```

**

```
No module named 'pygame'
No module named 'agent'
```

Anybody can help me with this? I really appreciated it.

Comment: Hi Mazikeen, welcome to SO! Can you please give us the python and pip versions installed, and where are they located? Also, can you try using 'pip3 install' and running the script via 'python3 x.py' ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `conda install` from anaconda prompt instead of `pip`

```
conda install pygame
```

Comment: (base) C:\Users\Eszter>conda install pygame
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - pygame

Comment: this issue is solved, but now the jupyter kernal has died after 10 mins. Any idea why?

Comment: When kernel dies as a result of library issues, you might not get any feedback as to what is causing it. Try running the code that is causing the kernel to die in a terminal or in ipython. Sometimes the issue occurs with tensorflow. use conda instead of pip to install libraries @Mazikeen